# Left align text inside a button in Android

Tags: java, android, xml

I want to align text of a button to the left, I don't know how to do this, please help me how to do this in the xml file. I didn´t find the properties for this.

Comment: Please rephrase your question :) it's so unclear

Comment: Telling people to google something that is A) missing from the API docs and B) non-obvious and C) a problem caused by Google's overlapping API calls that interfere with each other ... is  unhelpful.

Answer (score 157):

Maybe this will help you:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It was the `|center_vertical` part I was missing, thanks @M-Mohsin-Naeem

Comment: Should consider using android:gravity="start|center_vertical" instead of left

Comment: `center_vertical` automatically align the text to the left. I needed my text aligned to the right, so `center_vertical|right` worked for me. I didn't know I could do that with the pipe character, thanks!

Comment: This doesn't answer the original question. You are moving the button, not aligning the text label inside the button.

Answer (score 51):

You probably want both

```
    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
```

and then a little bit of space

```
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
```

to keep the text from running up against the left edge of the button.

(Adjust the amount of padding_left as appropriate for your button art.)

Comment: You mean: 
android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
android:paddingLeft="10dp"

Comment: So I do!  Thanks, fixed.

Answer (score 28):

`android:gravity="left"`

Hope This will help

Comment: thanks,  but this did not work to move the center of the button text, what I did was android:paddingRight=" dp" and that was it

Comment: I dont quite understand what do you mean,
can u explain further?

Comment: It's quite clear what he means. The text on the button should be aligned to the left inside the button. Next time read the question before recommending google.

Comment: Yeah, whats wrong with my code? `gravity` is to align text inside the button, `layout_gravity` is to align the button to the parent

Comment: @user1497577, put it inside the '<button />' element.

Answer (score 6):

```
android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
```

It will work but now you may need to add some padding left according to your requirement.

```
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably need BOTH the `android:gravity` AND the `android:layout_gravity` to align text to "left".

Answer (score 2):

This is combination from above that worked for me, icon on left and text left aligned with some padding

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/butt_labs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/dt_labjob"
    android:paddingLeft="10dip"
    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
    android:text="@string/l_labs" />
```

Answer (score 1):

As everyone else has mentioned, `"left|center_vertical"` works, but I have found that if left or right is not explicitly stated, most properties default to left.

So putting the following should be enough to get your text left-justified and vertically centered:

```
android:gravity="center_vertical"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have to support many different languages it is better to use `start` or `end` to position text. That way for *right to left (RTL) languages* it will still work.

**Example:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
        android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```